# Accidental overwriting of variable when parsing text file (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a text file with columns of data into curves (x and y value), however all curves turn out to have the same values when inspecting them, even though I feel they shouldn't.

Here is the minimum of my code that can show the problem:

```
    #creates the curves and sets their names given the first row in the text document
    for i, title in (enumerate(titles)):
        curveToAdd = Curve(titles[i].split()[0], UnitData(), UnitData())
        curveToAdd.yUnitData.unit = title.split()[1][1:-1]
        curveToAdd.xUnitData.unit = titlesWithTime[0].split()[1][1:-1]
        tempParsedCurves.append(curveToAdd)

    while isReading:
        text = f.readline()
        dotText = text.replace(",", ".").replace(".00", ".0")
        parts = dotText.split()

        # goes through the values in the current row
        for i, part in enumerate(parts):
            for j, tempParsedCurve in enumerate(tempParsedCurves):
                if len(parts) == len(titles) + 1: #incomplete rows teremine when to stop reading
                    #the current value is for the current curve
                    if tempParsedCurve.name == tempParsedCurves[i - 1].name:                    
                        #xValue is always in first column (time)
                        tempParsedCurves[i - 1].xUnitData.values.append(float(parts[0]))
                        #yValue depends on the index of the current curve
                        tempParsedCurves[i - 1].yUnitData.values.append(float(parts[j + 1]))
                else:
                    isReading = False
```

After the curves are created in the first for-loop, they are added to tempParsedCurves, which is then used when looping through the possibleCurves the values could be added to.

When a value is determined to belong to a curve, it gets added to the correct curve (tempParseCurves[i-1]) by first adding the x value and then y value. Im pretty sure this is correct beacuse the following print placed within the inner-most if-case shows the correct names and values for the curves:

```
    print("to curve " + tempParsedCurves[i - 1].name + ", appending x: " + str(float(parts[0])) + ", y: " + str(float(parts[j + 1])))
```

At this point everything seemed to work good, the values are getting added to their respective curve. ***However, if I try to loop through "tempParsedCurves" after the parsing is complete, all the curves have the same x and y values.***

Could this be due to me accidentaly refering to the same instance of one of the object when I actually should clone.clone/deepclone?

Comment: Have you considered using `pandas` to read in the columns/rows? Also: where is `tempParsedCurve.name` coming from?

Comment: That looks like it can be very useful, I will probably give it a try tomorrow! tempParsedCurve.name is coming from the curve name passed as the first parameter when initializing the Curve object (titles[i].split()[0])

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to troubleshoot without some sample data, however I think it maybe because you are referencing “parts” instead of “part” in the following 2 lines of code:

```
tempParsedCurves[i - 1].xUnitData.values.append(float(parts[0]))
                    #yValue depends on the index of the current curve
                    tempParsedCurves[i - 1].yUnitData.values.append(float(parts[j + 1]))
```